# CollapseAll with one document causes no text to display

Tags: xpages

I have some categorized views on individual xpages.  I have a button on the page which can collapse the views.

```
var viewPanel:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1");
try {
        viewPanel.gotoFirstPage();
     } 
     catch (e) {
     }
var model = viewPanel.getDataModel();
model.getDominoViewDataContainer().collapseAll();
```

If there is only one document in the view and the view is collapsed, then no text is displayed in the view.  Is anyone else seeing this behavior?

I can't tell you the grief this one caused me.  I never suspected in would be the collapse that was causing the document not to display.

Clarification:  The column titles are displayed.  It is that the document is not displayed when collapse all is used.  Also it looks it looks like no documents are being displayed after collapse all even when there are more than one document.   View in notes client displays fine.

Comment: I do have one view panel that uses a categorized view that does not exhibit this behavior.  Comparing differences now.  If someone know what causes this, plase speak up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out.  It seemed to be multiple issues.

1. I had a computed field in the first column, of the actual view, to show the count. View Panel does not seem to like this.  I moved the "count" column to the right beyond the categorized fields.
2. Some of the views seemed to have a problem wih the programmatic column.  I removed all of the $XX values and gave them my own name.
3. Ctrl-Shift-F9 in the client seemed to fix remaining issues with other views.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same thing when using 8.5.3 server, but a replica on Domino 9 does not appear to exhibit this behaviour. I haven't been able to determine other cause yet, but appreciate some of the items you described.